# FullCalendar dayClick js event not detaching

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-click-event

I have a fullcalendar in my webpage. The calendar has events. On `dayClick` event handler I am calling a function.

The problem is 1st time on click of a day box the function gets called 1 time. 2nd time the function is getting called 2 times, 3rd time 3 times..and so on.

*I can guess the problem is the day click event is not detaching.* But I am not able to solve it.

**The code:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    eventLimit: true,
    defaultView: 'month',
    editable: false,
    eventClick: function (event) {
        if (event.url) {
            window.open(baseUrl + event.url);
            return false;
        }
    },
    dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        var dateString = '';
        dateString = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format().split('T')[0];
        $('#popup').modal('toggle');
        $('#popup').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        AsyncFn().done(function (result) {
            AnotherAsyncFn(function () {
                SomeFunction();  //This function gets called multiple times                                           
                });
            });                   
        });                        
    }
});
```

I am not sure how to detach this event. May be by using `off` or `unbind`, but don't know exactly how.
Can anyone give some help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `off` method.

```
$('#popup').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#popup').off('shown.bs.modal');
    AsyncFn().done(function (result) {
        AnotherAsyncFn(function () {
            SomeFunction();  //This function gets called multiple times                                           
        });
    });                   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `jQuery.unbind()` before attaching the event again.

```
dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    var dateString = '';
    dateString = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format().split('T')[0];
    $('#popup').modal('toggle');
    $('#popup').unbind("shown.bs.modal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    AsyncFn().done(function (result) {
        AnotherAsyncFn(function () {
            SomeFunction();  //This function gets called multiple times                                           
            });
        });                   
    });                        
}
```